# Bash redirection not creating text file

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection

I have the following code:

```
RAN=$RANDOM
STDOUT="out${RAN}.txt"
STDERR="err${RAN}.txt"
Rscript ...solvers/script.r ${CONFIG_PARAMS} 1> ${STDOUT} 2> ${STDERR}
```

Getting the following error:

```
error: out30304.txt: No such file or directory
```

But shouldn't the line beginning with `Rscript` be creating the text file?

EDIT: the ellipsis is not actually present in the code, it's there to remove unnecessary information.

EDIT2: More code for context. Again, all paths are reduced for ease of reading & security:

```
# 2020-04-08 12:33:17 EDT: Estimating execution time using 2% of 590400 = 11808
Error : == irace == running command ''.../tuning/target-runner' 1 1 1042861479 .../tuning/Instances/README   9 11728 0.6487 0.8525 226 2>&1' had status 1
== irace == The call to targetRunner was:
.../tuning/target-runner 1 1 1042861479 .../tuning/Instances/README   9 11728 0.6487 0.8525 226
== irace == The output was:
.../tuning/target-runner: line 57: 74728 Killed                  Rscript .../tblupcpp.r ${CONFIG_PARAMS} > ${STDOUT} 2> ${STDERR}
Wed Apr  8 16:34:10 UTC 2020: .../tuning/target-runner: error: out30304.txt: No such file or directory
== irace == This is not a bug in irace, but means that something failed when running the command(s) above or they were terminated before completion. Try to run the command(s) above from the execution directory '.../solvers' to investigate the issue. See also Appendix B (targetRunner troubleshooting checklist) of the User Guide (https://cran.r-project.org/package=irace/vignettes/irace-package.pdf).
 Error : == irace == running command ''.../tuning/target-runner' 3 1 1042861479 .../tuning/Instances/README   8 18796 0.5252 0.5963 327 2>&1' had status 1
== irace == The call to targetRunner was:
.../tuning/target-runner 3 1 1042861479 .../tuning/Instances/README   8 18796 0.5252 0.5963 327
== irace == The output was:
.../tuning/target-runner: line 57: 74727 Killed                  Rscript .../tblupcpp.r ${CONFIG_PARAMS} > ${STDOUT} 2> ${STDERR}
Wed Apr  8 16:34:04 UTC 2020: .../tuning/target-runner: error: out22101.txt: No such file or directory
== irace == This is not a bug in irace, but means that something failed when running the command(s) above or they were terminated before completion. Try to run the command(s) above from the execution directory '.../solvers' to investigate the issue. See also Appendix B (targetRunner troubleshooting checklist) of the User Guide (https://cran.r-project.org/package=irace/vignettes/irace-package.pdf).
Error: == irace == A child process triggered a fatal error
In addition: Warning message:
In parallel::mclapply(experiments, exec.target.runner, mc.preschedule = !scenario$loadBalancing,  :
  2 function calls resulted in an error
Execution halted
```

Comment: What's the exact `Rscript` invocation and the exact error message you're getting? It looks like you've typed both in by hand which makes me suspect we're not seeing the real mistake. (Bash errors normally start with `bash:`.)

Comment: Also, what's the value of CONFIG_PARAMS?

Comment: I have simplified it but it is copy-pasted. I'll add the full code in now.

Comment: `CONFIG_PARAMS=$*` - in other words they are parameterised, and you can see them now in the edited question.

Comment: If you try to redirect output to a file in a folder that doesn't exist then you'll get that error.

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: Your shell script looks fine. It looks like this is a problem with how you're using `Rscript` or `irace` or whatever. I don't know what those things are but this doesn't look like a bash problem.